# Error using SQL 'With' clause

Tags: sqlite

This is the query that I am using. I am getting an error with this query. 'syntax error near 'WITH' clause.

```
WITH RECURSIVE under_cust (affiliation_id, from_customer_id, to_customer_id, to_name,     parent_customer_type, child_customer_type, level) 
 AS (SELECT af.affiliation_id, 
       from_customer_id, 
       to_customer_id, 
       to_name, 
       parent_customer_type, 
       child_customer_type, 
       0 LEVEL 
     FROM   affiliation af, 
                customer c 
         WHERE  to_customer_id <> from_customer_id 
                AND af.from_customer_id = c.customer_id 
                AND af.to_customer_id = 1000022559337 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT af.affiliation_id, 
                af.from_customer_id, 
                af.to_customer_id, 
                af.to_name, 
                af.parent_customer_type, 
                af.child_customer_type, 
                under_cust.level + 1 LEVEL 
         FROM   customer c, 
                affiliation af 
                JOIN under_cust smr 
                  ON smr.from_customer_id = af.to_customer_id 
         WHERE  af.from_customer_id = c.customer_id 
) SELECT affiliation_id, 
   to_customer_id   parent, 
   from_customer_id child, 
   to_name, 
   parent_customer_type, 
   child_customer_type, 
   level 
FROM   under_cust
```

Comment: Which version of sqlite do you have? Common table expressions were added in 3.8.3 - http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Comment: the file extension says '.sqlite3'. how to find the version?

Comment: How are you running the query? If it's the sqlite3 shell, then you can find the version with e.g. `sqlite3 --version`

Comment: Or execute `SELECT sqlite_version();`.

Comment: OK Thank you. it is older version (3.7.17). Need to think an alternative without using 'with ' clause..

Answer (score 7):

Common table expressions and the `WITH` syntax were introduced only recently in [sqlite version 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3).

If you run the query on an older version, you get the syntax error.

Either upgrade your sqlite or make your code work without the `WITH` syntax.