# Sqlite "WITH" syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I have this code, with this error: "Query Error: near "WITH": syntax error Unable to execute statement" from both SqliteMan and from Node-webkit (latest).

```
WITH RECURSIVE FT_CTE(*) AS (
   SELECT pID, cID FROM brFTNode_Children 
   WHERE pID = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.pID, e.cID FROM brFTNode_Children e
   INNER JOIN FT_CTE ftCTE ON (ftCTE.cID = e.pID)
)
SELECT * FROM FT_CTE;
```

The Sqlite document clearly stated that it supports "WITH" statement.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you running? `WITH` [was introduced in SQLite 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3). If you have an older version it isn't supported.

Comment: Run `SELECT sqlite_version();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error using SQL 'With' clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036310/error-using-sql-with-clause)