# SQLITE Recursive Query

Tags: sqlite, recursion

I've found an interesting recursive query here (http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10486/recursive-cte-and-ordering-of-the-hierarchical-result.aspx) and I adapted to my needs, but is not working.

Here's the code:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS lvl, collectionID, collectionName, parentCollectionID, CAST(collectionID AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
           FROM collections WHERE parentCollectionID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.lvl + 1, c.collectionID, c.collectionName, c.parentCollectionID, CAST(p.Sort + '/' + CAST(c.collectionID AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(128))
          FROM collections c
          INNER JOIN cte p ON p.collectionID = c.parentCollectionID
        )
SELECT 
collectionID, 
SPACE(lvl * 4) + collectionName AS collectionName, 
Sort,
parentCollectionID 
FROM cte ORDER BY Sort;
```

I receive this message: "Kernel error: near "WITH": syntax error"

Please, what I have to do to fix it?
I'm using SQLIte 3.8.2

Comment: I haven't looked at the query itself, but Common Table Expressions weren't added to SQLite until 3.8.6 http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_6.html

Comment: Thank you Ben Grimm. I'll try to upgrade my SQLIte.

Comment: Hi Ben Grimm, is it possible to do the same thing without CTE and With clause?

Comment: You can achieve _similar_ results without CTEs by constructing the query manually with self joins. But if you need real recursion without CTEs, you'll have to do it outside of SQLite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error using SQL 'With' clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036310/error-using-sql-with-clause)